# Status code 400 when sending a Post request in json format

Tags: java, json

In response to my request comes `400` error, checked in postman there OK. Tell me what's wrong in the code?

**My code**

```
public void doPost() throws SQLException{
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://sbt-ot-289.ca.sbrf.ru:8080/ptd_integration/check_clients_stub");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection succesfull");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**stack trace**

```
Connection succesfull
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://sbt-ot-289.ca.sbrf.ru:8080/ptd_integration/check_clients_stub
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
                at com.company.RequestSender.doPost(RequestSender.java:34)
                at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:10)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

**Result in postman**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved

```
public void doPost() throws SQLException{
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://sbt-ot-289.ca.sbrf.ru:8080/ptd_integration/");
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();
    System.out.println("Connection succesfull");
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(usersCollection().toString());
    wr.flush();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int HttpResult = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
        String line;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }else {
        System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain what changes you have made and how you resolved it